# Html toggle image and save the last status

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of making a page for reporting street light faults, and I want this page to be open for contributions by public users.

I need to superimpose the locations of the lighting poles on a map image (not Google map)

The images will be like a bulb  with two different images (on and off)

I want the user to have the ability to change the status of the light pole on clicking the image. 
I need the page to save the last image selected by the user, so that when I get to open the page,  i get the last status of the lighting pole on and off.

I am stuck in the last part, which is saving the last image selected by the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you should be doing is performing the actual save as the user clicks on the bulb icon

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show the relevant parts of your code? Without it is difficult for the people to give you concrete and specific answers. Thanks!

Comment: Well I will tell ya what, if you are on different computers, javascript is not the answer, you will need to go server side like php

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can I do the actual save and change the source of the first image.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">



<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nae81dr8/

Comment: @ScottSelby  how can I do the actual save?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this question kind of implies that you already have a working concept of the user making a selection of a bulb (maybe from a  dropdown or something) and then can change the status to either on or off and then save the changed status.

If all that was working then you could come and ask the question of how to get this save process to happen during the click event , and also how to get the proper bulb images to  show up as either on or off on initial page load.

Since it seems like you do not have even that much completed I think it may be best that you re-write your question to more specifically what exactly you need and how you are going about it , and what code you have so far.

- do you have the appropiate bulbs showing up as on or off on the page load?
- do you have the location of the bulb ( meaning which bulb on the map) accessible to  you in the javascript on the click event?
- do you have an api set up server side that you can send an id of the bulb and a status to perform the save?

after those are all either completed - or asked in another question then we can help with problems like keeping the map up to date when other users make an update.  with getting the save to happen on the actual click, etc

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. I already have a concept and I already built a small page http://www.i-m.mx/mtawheed/report-light-fault/ . I counted the light poles and located them on the map. I have put the image of the lighting poles as an html to toggle the image of the bulb on and off. What I need is how can I get the user to save the last selected status, and not to return to the first status on page refresh. I am very new to HTML, I am trying to help the people in my district to report the faulty poles. I will collect these faults from the map and report them to the authority.

Comment: Any suggestions on that are very welcome. Unfortunately I don't understand what is the api server.